# Acessar uma matriz na função

Tags: c, c++, funções, matriz

Estou tendo que criar uma função num arquivo separado da main. Esta função receberá os valores de uma matriz, somará todos os valores por linha, armazenará a soma em um vetor e, em seguida, imprimirá o respectivo vetor. Porém, não estou conseguindo imprimir os resultados desejados. O arquivo da main está certinho para receber as matrizes.

Este é o código da função.

```
#include <iostream>
void sum(float A[], float v[], const short N, const short M)
{
    int i,j;

    for (j=0; j<M; j++)
    {

        for ( i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            v[i] += A[i*M+j];

        }
    }
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

E esse é o arquivo da main onde digito a matriz, imprimo a matriz e recebo a função.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funcoes.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const short n=3,m=4;
    float a[n][m];
    int i,j;
    float v[n],resul;
    for( i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for( j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cout << "Digite [" << i+1 << "][" << j+1 << "] : ";
            cin >>a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for( i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for( j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    sum(&a[n][m],&v[n],n,m);

    return 0;
}
```

Vale ressaltar, que eu sei que poderia escrever tudo na main. Ficaria até mais fácil. Porém, eu **NECESSITO** que a função seja criada fora da main.

Comment: O que ta dando de erro?

Comment: Não sei por qual motivo você não declara o parâmetro de sua função como um array bidimensional. A chamada de sua função deve ser: `sum(a, v, n, m);`.

Comment: Quando você faz `&a[n][m]` e `&v[n]` está se referindo ao endereço da posição específica do array que, aliás, estão fora dos limites do array.

Answer (score 0):

Teu programa tem alguns errinhos.

Primeiro: o vetor v que você tá usando pra somar não foi inicializado e portanto vai ter uma valor aleatório que se encontrava na memória anteriormente. A seguinte inicialização na hora da declaração pode resolver isso facilmente (ou se preferir, faz um loop de 0 até n - 1 zerando cada elemento):

```
float v[n] = {0};
```

Segundo: A forma como a função foi declarada e como os parâmetros da matriz e do vetor são passados estão acessando valores fora do que foi reservado na memória. Você está passando o endereço do último elemento do vetor na chamada da função e dentro da função esse último elemento é tratado como se fosse o primeiro. Altera a chamada para:

```
   sum(&a[0][0], v, n, m);
```